# Derivation of geodesic equations from the definition of parallel vector fieds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic, general-relativity

I am reading "Differentiable Manifolds: A Theoretical Physics Approach" by Torres del Castillo. On page 116 of the book the author gives the equations for a parallel vector field along a curve $C$ as follows:

$$\frac{d(Y^k \circ C)}{dt} + \frac{d(x^i \circ C)}{dt} (\Gamma_{ji}^k \circ C)(Y^j \circ C) = 0$$

Then defines geodesics as the curves on which $C'$ is parallel to itself along C and gives the following equation:

$$\frac{d^2(x ^k \circ C)}{dt^2} +(\Gamma_{ji}^k \circ C) \frac{d(x^i \circ C)}{dt} \frac{d(x^j \circ C)}{dt}   = 0$$

since we have that the coefficients of $C'$ are $Y^j = \frac{d(x^j \circ C)}{dt}$

But in my head, for example the first term of the first equation would become

$$\frac{d^2(x ^k \circ C \circ C)}{dt^2}\neq \frac{d^2(x ^k \circ C)}{dt^2}$$

which doesn't really makes sense. So how does this follow?

Comment: You're being too wedded to symbols without thinking about what they mean. If $Y$ is a vector field defined *only* on $C$, then in fact we should not have the $\circ C$ in the first term. If $Y$ is a vector field defined everywhere, then you need it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. Just to confirm in this case we would have $Y^j = \frac{d (x^j)}{dt}$, right because the vector field is being evaluated on $C$?

Comment: No, what you just typed makes no sense. $t$ has meaning only as the independent variable parametrizing $C$ (note that the author is using the same symbol for the parametrization and for its image curve).

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense. I think I need to go back to the definitions and think about it a bit to understand.